# how can I join 3 table with 2 table data sum

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table. purchase_order, goods_receive, purchase_transaction.

*** My purchase_order id is show as order_id. 
 1. I need sum all Quantity form goods_receive table as order id.
 2. secondly I need sum amount form purchase_transaction tabel as order id.

see my attachment image for more clear >>

[image]

```html
<?php


include("db.php");



$sqlnew="SELECT purchase_order.id , purchase_order.quantity,
 purchase_order.unit_price, purchase_order.total_amount, 
 sum(goods_receive.quantity) as qua , sum(purchase_transaction.amount) as amount 
      
       
  FROM purchase_order
 JOIN goods_receive  ON purchase_order.id = goods_receive.order_id


 JOIN purchase_transaction ON purchase_order.id = goods_receive.order_id

 GROUP BY goods_receive.order_id";

$resultnew=mysql_query($sqlnew);



?>

            <table class="table table-bordered data-table" border="1">
              <thead>
                <tr>
    <th>Order ID</th>
    
           
                  <th>Quantity</th>
       <th> Receive Quantity</th>
                  <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Total Amount</th>
       <th>Paid Amount</th>
      
  
    
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
     <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultnew)){
?>
                <tr class="gradeX">
     <td><a href="purchase_order_single_details.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
    
                  <td><?php echo $rows['quantity']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['qua']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $rows['unit_price']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $rows['total_amount']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows['amount']; ?></td>
   

    
    </tr>
    
    
    
    
    <?php
}
?>

    
    
             
               </tbody>
            </table>
    
          </div>
        </div>
  
  
  
  
  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Footer-part-->
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join with subqueries that calculate the totals you want

```
SELECT po.order_id, po.quantity, gr.quantity AS receive_quantity, 
    po.unit_price, po.total_amount, pt.amount AS paid_amount
FROM purchase_order AS po
JOIN (SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
      FROM good_receive
      GROUP BY order_id) AS gr ON gr.order_id = po.order_id
JOIN (SELECT order_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
      FROM purchase_transaction
      GROUP BY order_id) AS pt ON pt.order_id = po.order_id
```